# Calculating Closing and Opening Balance in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table 'transactions(txDate, amount, txType) where txType can "credit" or "debit".
I need to get an opening and closing balance when returning transactions between two dates.

The first row of the results should be  the Opening Balance, then a list of all tx between the dates and the last row to be a Closing balance

Getting the list isn't a train smash but for the balances, I currently have the following

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS [Opening Balance]
FROM 
(
    SELECT SUM([Amount]) amount
    FROM [dbo].[Transaction]
    WHERE [txDate] <= @startDate
    AND [txType] = 'credit'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 0 - SUM([Amount]) amount
    FROM [dbo].[Transaction]
    WHERE [TransactionDate] <= @startDate
    AND [txType] = 'debit'
) Transactions
```

this gives a very big amount than what it should be.

And for the Closing balance, I have no idea how to go about it

Comment: it would be good to include some sample data and expected result for them

Comment: What's a train smash?

Comment: Have you used window functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE` in `SUM`

```
select  sum(case when txType = 'credit' and transactionDate <= @startDate 
                then amount end) - 
        sum(case when txType = 'debit' and transactionDate <= @startDate 
                then amount end)[Opening Balance],
        sum(case when txType = 'credit' and transactionDate <= @endDate 
                then amount end) - 
        sum(case when txType = 'debit' and transactionDate <= @endDate 
                then amount end)[Closing Balance]
from transaction
```

Comment: Thanks... Works great!!

Comment: Thank you very much , the answer give my a good idea for my big query :)